# jQuery carousel with navigation and central highlighted thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I have been baltting with this problem for most of the day so any help really would be very much appreciated.

As the title says I am looking for a carousel which has a next and previous navigation, attatched to the larger image. As well as that I would like to have thumbnails, pretty much similar to this page.

http://friquemag.net/demos/etalage/?v=132

Now my issue is that when I navigate left and right, using the buttons on the right hand side eventually I get to the end of the thumbnails and it jumps all the way to the left, scrolling past all of the previously viewed thumbnails and I was hoping somebody could tell me how I get the thumbnails to scroll in an infinite loop like the main image at the top.

I have searched on Stack Over Flow and found this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184719/auto-content-slider-with-carousel-thumbnails-navigation-in-jquery

However sadly it does not answer my question.

A link to the js file can be found here

`http://friquemag.net/demos/etalage/js/jquery.etalage.min.js`

And the css file here

`http://friquemag.net/demos/etalage/css/etalage.css`

Any help on resolving this issue really would be very much appreciated.

Thanking everyone in advance

Cameron

Comment: Are you trying to make an infinite loop with the plugin mentioned above or make your own plugin based on the plugin mentioned above?

Comment: I am attempting to create an infinite loop using the plugin as I dont have the skill level to create one of my own. I dont have to use the plugin provided if someone can point me in the direction of a plugin which does exactly what I want then I am happy to use an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

So you need an infinite carousel with thumbnails?
Try this one - http://showcase.awkwardgroup.com/

[Here is the download and the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/awkwardgroup/awkward-showcase/wiki/Home)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, however this is not what I want. Yes I do want an jquery carousel which has an infinite loop, however i also want thumbnails, not numbers and I dont want the thumbnails to loop back to one, I want them to loop in an infinite manner in a similar way to the main image, much like the original link I posted in the question, but with the thumbnails not returning to number one.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/23-thumbs-gallery.html).

Here is the [documentation](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VWWRMs-qpBc)